# Play last audio element relative to recent <script> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I've got a jQuery script which can be inserted by a user (inside a CMS). This script converts the last link to an mp3-file (last means: relative to the recent  tag) to a HTML5  element and inserts a play button below this audio. Untill this point, the script works well, but I didn't get the playing done, the button doesn't play the audio file.
What's going wrong there?

My code (a fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xysnnnLo/1/)):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/5/16797_1460740933.mp3">SOUND-1</a>
<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/5/16983_1461335348.mp3">SOUND-2</a>

<script class="auto-play-button">
  function LinkToAudio(element) {
    var audioURL = jQuery(element).attr('href');
    var audioName = jQuery(element).text();
    jQuery(element).before('<br/>');
    jQuery(element).after('<br/><audio src="' + audioURL + '" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio><br/>');
  }
  //converting last mp3-link (relative to this <script> tag) into HTML5 audio element
  LinkToAudio($('a[href$="mp3"]:last'));
  var audioelement = $('audio:last');
  // Insert Play Button after last <audio> tag (relative to this <script> tag) 
  $('<button id="audio">Play Sound above</button>').insertAfter(audioelement);
  $("body").on("click", "button", audioelement.play());

</script>

<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/4/16539_1460655601.mp3">SOUND-3</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("body").on("click", "button", audioelement.play());`

First thing I can see is your button handler will not run as expected - it will try to fire the `play` method right away since you are invoking it directly. Second, the `play` method needs to be invoked on the audio element, and not on the JQuery element, hence the `...audioelement.play is not a function` error.

Try this:

`$("body").on("click", "button", function() {
    audioelement[0].play();
});`

Edit: Original poster's intent is to have the script tag be reusable as a snippet in some sort of WYSIWG setting, fiddle + snippet updated with this in mind.

[Click to see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drscodelab/0nnen4va)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/5/16797_1460740933.mp3">SOUND-1</a>
<script>
    // Add buttons and otherwise manipulate the dom
    function LinkToAudio(p_element, p_callback) {
        var audioURL = $(p_element).attr('href');
        var audioName = $(p_element).text();
        // Dom for the audio tag
        var audioTag = '<audio src="' + audioURL + '" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio>';
        // Dom for the play button
        var audioPlayButton = '<button id="audio">Play Sound above</button>';
        // Add a audio tag and play button after the element
        $(p_element).after('<br/>' + audioTag + '<br/>' + audioPlayButton + '<br/>');
     // Add the callback to the button
        $(p_element).nextAll('button:first').on('click', p_callback);
    }
  
    // Define our button click handler
    function AudioButtonHandler(evt) {
     // Once clicked, find the first audio tag located before the button
           var relativeAudioTag = $(evt.target).prevAll('audio:first')[0];
     console.log(evt.target, relativeAudioTag);
        // Play the sound!
        relativeAudioTag.play();
    }

    var thisAudio = $('a[href$="mp3"]:last');
    LinkToAudio(thisAudio, AudioButtonHandler);
</script>

<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/5/16983_1461335348.mp3">SOUND-2</a>
<a href="http://www.freesfx.co.uk/rx2/mp3s/4/16539_1460655601.mp3">SOUND-3</a>
<script>
    // Add buttons and otherwise manipulate the dom
    function LinkToAudio(p_element, p_callback) {
        var audioURL = $(p_element).attr('href');
        var audioName = $(p_element).text();
        // Dom for the audio tag
        var audioTag = '<audio src="' + audioURL + '" type="audio/mpeg" preload="none"></audio>';
        // Dom for the play button
        var audioPlayButton = '<button id="audio">Play Sound above</button>';
        // Add a audio tag and play button after the element
        $(p_element).after('<br/>' + audioTag + '<br/>' + audioPlayButton + '<br/>');
     // Add the callback to the button
        $(p_element).nextAll('button:first').on('click', p_callback);
    }
  
    // Define our button click handler
    function AudioButtonHandler(evt) {
     // Once clicked, find the first audio tag located before the button
           var relativeAudioTag = $(evt.target).prevAll('audio:first')[0];
     console.log(evt.target, relativeAudioTag);
        // Play the sound!
        relativeAudioTag.play();
    }

    var thisAudio = $('a[href$="mp3"]:last');
    LinkToAudio(thisAudio, AudioButtonHandler);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jfyeqy7d/2/ I inserted a clone of your script below the 3rd sound file. Now faultily the buttons generated are playing the same sound file and not the one above them. Think audioelement[0].play() is the culpable …

Comment: On the fiddle you provided, I still see the inline function invocation. Have you tried using the anonymous function I provided above? I forked your fiddle and replaced the button handler on line 16:  
  
https://jsfiddle.net/wymy1abv/1/  
  
Also, the script will fire and find the last audio tag relative to its position with the a tags, so to have it find the last tag, you would have to move the script after all of them for it to work. See this fiddle:  
  
https://jsfiddle.net/drscodelab/27u6eod8/

Comment: If you want your script to find the last a / audio tag regardless of its relative position in the dom, you can wait until the document is ready before finding the last instance. If this doesn't clash with your current setup, I would recommend using this method. See this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/drscodelab/0s0h9bga/

Comment: Sorry for being so tenacious! I should clearify: In the texteditor of a CMS users can upload and insert files (mp3-files). On one page there can be a lot of textareas and each textarea can contain a lot of file urls. Now a user should be able to place a snippet (HTML, JS) below a link and as a result the audio file immediately before/above that snippet gets a play button; only links followed by that snippet should be converted. That snippet has to be a fixed code (so I chose the "audio:last"-approach). If you could show me how to invoke multiple buttons on a page - I would be very happy!

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/drscodelab/0nnen4va/ - I misunderstood the part where it needed to be a reusable snippet. If you need to be able to drop standalone snippets after a link to add the button, this should suffice; but in my opinion, I would **highly recommend** marking any <a> tags with an attribute or some sort of signifier up front, and then enable the buttons in one final sweep at the very end. This would be best practice as it keeps  your code in one place, making it reusable and much cleaner. I'll update the answer above if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much – the solution in your answer works great, but you're definitly right: keeping everything in place is better; i'll do it in the end by assigning indexed classes / IDs to audio and corresponding buttons.